# how to quote valueFrom helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

This is my secret file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ftp-credentials
  namespace: {{ $.Values.metadata.namespace }}
data:
  ftp_password: <secret>
  ftp_user: <secret>
type: Opaque
```

ftp_user is a base64 for user that will send to env of os. for some reason I need to quote the user to set into env. I mean FTP_USER="user" instead of FTP_USER=user.
How to do that?
In my spec section I tried this:

```yaml
    spec:
        ...
        env:
          - name: FTP_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: ftp-credentials
                key: ftp_user
          - name: FTP_USER2
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: ftp-credentials
                key: {{ ftp_user | quote }}
```

`FTP_USER` is not quoted, `FTP_USER2` rises an error: `function "ftp_user" not defined`

Comment: How about storing the value in the secret with the quotes?

Comment: there's no ftp_user variable from helm point of view. If you really can't fix that container not to require those extra quotes, I would add those quotes in the value written into my secret.

Comment: @whites11 values are in base64 format

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Helm templates to manipulate the contents of the environment variable at container runtime.  The Helm templating runs once when you install the chart, so you will get a fixed `valueFrom: { secretKeyRef: }` structure, and you can do the things Kubernetes allows at that point.

The first syntactic answer is that the `name:` and `key:` need to match what's in the Secret, with no particular manipulation.  You don't need to quote them specifically, unless there's some ambiguity at the YAML level as to what it is (using `true` as a key, for example).

```yaml
- name: FTP_USER2
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: ftp-credentials
      key: ftp_user         # <-- just a fixed string
```

This is exactly the same as your existing `$FTP_USER` variable.  If you want to put double quotes around that value, [embedding the value of one environment variable in another](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/) is one of the few string manipulations it's possible to do in Kubernetes.  You might be looking for something more like

```yaml
- name: FTP_USER2
  value: '"$(FTP_USER)"'
```

Note the single quotes on the outside to indicate a quoted YAML string, and then the contents of the string contain double quotes.  Without the outer single quotes, the double quotes would be consumed at the YAML layer.